# Azure Functions App access files from Shared Path

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to read files from a shared path In **Azure VM** using azure functions app.

```
let networkDrive = require('windows-network-drive');
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {    

context.log('start with');
networkDrive.mount("\\\\<IP Address>\\path","Y",'username','password')
.then(function(drive){
context.log("success");
context.log(drive);
})
.catch(function(error){
      context.log(error);
})
};
```

But I am getting Access is Denied.  However if I try the same code from console of the Azure VM it is working as expected.  Are there any config changes/settings to be changed in functions app/Azure VM to make this work. 
Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your VM and the function into the same VNET.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not time out but denying access it seems your network share is already opened on a public IP. This can be dangerous for brute force attacks and you need some authentication.

The function app's user / service account is currently obviously unknown to your VM. 
You can

- connect both function app and your VM to a Azure AD, so you can use a common security principal to secure and access your share
- move you shared data to [Azure Storage File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) service. This works fine without AD and you simply use an access token in your function app.
- connect both VM and function app to a single private VNET and find a solution with anonymous access or a security principal.

I'd recommend the 2nd solution.